# How to check who is taking most of the bandwidth?

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2

I have couple web applications on my windows server 2008 r2. Running on IIS 7.5.
I know they crawled not just by GOOGLE search engine.
Is there anyway to check what IPs makes most of the requests to the applications?

Comment: Slightly off-topic. Better suited for http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go, right-click on the Website in Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager tool, go to the Web Site tab, and check the Enable Logging box. You can customize what information you want to log..you can log client's IP address then you can see logging report.

hope this helps..